# In double slit experiment, has the energy of the particle detected at the interference screen been measured and shown equal to the source particle's?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, double-slit-experiment

According to path integral theory, it *can be assumed* that a particle travelling from a point A to B (in an experiment that has not been designed to detect the path) takes all the possible paths from A to B.

(Please note that I use the words 'can be assumed' because I know that there is a debate whether the particle *really* takes all the paths that are considered in path integral or not.)

Now, energy of a particle is closely related to its momentum in quantum mechanics. So, in a double slit experiment, we can setup the detector at the interference screen so that it not only detects the position of the individual particles, but also their energy. This will not violate uncertainty principle because we will still not have the knowledge of the direction of the velocity of the particle, but only the magnitude of energy.

Now, being able to detect the energy of particles in a double slit experiment will be interesting because then we will be able to find out whether the energy of the detected particle is equal to that of the input particle or not.

If it is equal, then it would mean that the energy is conserved during the path. Yet, according to the path integral, the particle *can be assumed to* take all the possible paths. Since we know the initial and final energy of the particle, this means that we can only consider those paths in path integral where the energy fluctuates only in the middle of the path!

So, is it theoretically possible to detect the energy of the individual particles at the detectors in the double slit experiment. If yes, then theoretically, is the energy conserved at the start and the end of the path. And most importantly, do you know of any experiment that has been done to detect the energy of the individual particles at the interference screen. Please give me the links to the paper discussing this.

Comment: A observation of different frequencies (colours) for detected photons on the observers screen from the sources photons never was observed. If you could observe a difference it would be a big surprise. Anyway the question is a very interesting.